# Symbolic link all files in subfolders to one directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm trying to find a way to symbolically link files from many subdirectories to a single directory. I assume the best way will be to use a batch file and looping, but I'm not sure how to approach it. An example:

```
Source

-Directory
    -Subdirectory
        -file1
        -...
    -Subdirectory
        -file1
        -...
    -...

Target

-Directory
    -file1
    -file2
    -...
```

So the target would be a single directory containing all the files from all the subdirectories of the source.

Comment: What is your plan if files in two or more directories have the same name?

Comment: There shouldn't be, but it would be okay to just add a (1) or (2) or something like that. I wouldn't want to skip them but if it's necessary that's okay too.

Comment: You just use a `FOR /R` to iterate the directory structure and use the `MKLINK` command to create the link in that consolidated folder.

Comment: I essentially answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68570219/1417694) yesterday but the user wanted to do it for directories.  So you should be able to make a few small code changes in that code to solve what you want to do.